# Closedxml: can't download file and immediately send it via mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, closedxml

I want to download an excel file and automatically send the file to a mailadress aswell. Downloading the file works, but when I include the code for sending mails, it throws a FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project\Taijitan\Taijitan\O soto gari.xlsx'.'.

I noticed that when downloading the file, it automatically goes to the Downloads folder on my pc. When I uncomment the mail code, it doesn't seem to download, instead it just loads before throwing the error I mentioned above. I tried using Path.GetFullPath(name) to find the excel file so that I don't have to hardcode any paths (in case any of my colleagues have a different path), but it doesn't seem to work.

**Controller**

```
 public IActionResult GenerateList(int id)
    {
        Lesson lesson = _lessonRepository.GetBy(id);
        var download = lesson.GetCommentsList();
        string file = lesson.Name + ".xlsx";
        MailSender.SendListMail(lesson.Name, file);
        return download;
    }
```

**Generate excel + download**

```
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public IActionResult GetCommentsList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        var wb = new XLWorkbook();
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Comments");
        foreach (var comment in Comments)
        {
            list.Add(comment.Body);
        }

        string name = Name + "comment";
        ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = name;
        ws.Range(1, 1, 1, 1).AddToNamed("Titles");
        var CommentsRange = ws.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(list.AsEnumerable());
        var titlesStyle = wb.Style;
        titlesStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        titlesStyle.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        titlesStyle.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Blue;
        titlesStyle.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;
        wb.NamedRanges.NamedRange("Titles").Ranges.Style = titlesStyle;
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        wb.SaveAs(name + ".xlsx");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            wb.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Flush();
            return new FileContentResult(stream.ToArray(),
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                FileDownloadName = name + ".xlsx"
            };
        }
    }
```

**MailSender**

```
 public static void SendListMail(string list, string file)
    {
        MailAddress Sender = new MailAddress("SenderEmail@gmail.com", "CommentsSender");
        MailAddress Receiver = new MailAddress("ReceiverEmail@gmail.com", "Comments inbox");
        const string SenderPassword = "password123";

        string Attachment = Path.GetFullPath(file);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Sender.Address, SenderPassword),
            Timeout = 30000
        };
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(Sender, Receiver)
        {
            Subject = list,
            Body = "List in attachment",
            Attachments = {new Attachment(Attachment)}

        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out where it goes wrong and how I can solve this.
My guess is it has something to do with synchronization (don't send the mail until the download is complete) and Path.GetFullPath() not checking outside the solutionfolder.

**EDIT**
Just noticed that when I try to send an email without the attachment, it sends the mail, but doesn't download anything, and the loading icon in the tab keeps spinning.

**EDIT 2** Figured out the first problem, the placement of the return statement in the download method caused a loop.
Now I'm still having the could not find file error.

Comment: Make sure you close file in code.  Then search c: drive for file "gari.xlsx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be a dumb mistake. File got saved with the value of 'name' (file.Name + "comment.xlsx", but the download/email sender was looking for file.Name + ".xlsx" (didn't have "comment" in its name)